# Is the Pythagorean Theorem true for infinitesimal leg?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, infinitesimals

In Newtonian Physics (Classical Mechanics) a body rotates around another (massive) body with constant circular speed ω (stationary trajectory) eternally. The linear velocity v is perpendicular to the radius and the force F is along radius and hence perpendicular to v. F induces acceleration 'a' (F=ma) which in time dt induces dv along the force. E.g. v and dv are strictly perpendicular. This two are added like vectors and the sum is again v, but not in the same direction as v but a bit tilted toward the second (the massive) body.
This seems to be very much in conflict with the Pythagorean Theorem (PT). Physicists insist that this is due to the infinitesimal character of dv, but this nevertheless does not violate PT.
E.g. adding  a perpendicular dv to v leads to the same magnitude of v (not $\sqrt{v^{2}+\left( dv\right) ^{2}}$) but this is not violation of PT.
I am in total misunderstanding. In fact they insist that this happens because while dv is infiniesimal than $\left( dv\right) ^{2}=0$. I don’t believe this is also true. So the question is: Does PT hold for infinitesimal leg or not and how is it possible v+dv to equal v and simultaneously PT to be true?

Comment: $v$ and $\sqrt{v^2+dv^2}$ are the same to first order in $dv$, that's all.

Answer (score 6):

Expanding @Intelligenti pauca's comment, the power series for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in terms of $y$ centered at $0$ starts as
$$\lvert x\rvert + \frac{y^2}{2\lvert x\rvert} + \frac{y^4}{8 \lvert x\rvert^3} + \frac{y^6}{16\lvert x\rvert^5} +\cdots$$
So, to first order with respect to $y$, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\approx \lvert x\rvert$.

Before seeing how this interacts with calculating $\frac{d\lvert \mathrm{v}\rvert}{dt}$, let's calculate the derivative directly so we can believe it's zero at least mathematically. Write $v_x$ and $v_y$ for the two components of $\mathrm{v}$.  Taking derivatives, we get
$$\frac{d\lvert\mathrm{v}\rvert}{dt} = \frac{d\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}{dt} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}}\left(v_x\frac{d v_x}{dt} + v_y\frac{d v_y}{dt}\right) = \frac{1}{\lvert \mathrm{v}\rvert}\left(v_x\frac{d v_x}{dt} + v_y\frac{d v_y}{dt}\right)$$
When we evaluate at the $t$ where $v_x=v$ and $v_y=0$, which by physics is when $\frac{d v_x}{dt}=0$ (non-rigorously, this is that "$\mathrm{v}$ and $d\mathrm{v}$ are orthogonal"), then we can see the derivative evaluates to $0$.

Now let's use the power series to compute the derivative.  Substituting in $v_x$ and $v_y$, we get
$$\lvert\mathrm{v}\rvert = \lvert v_x\rvert + \frac{v_y^2}{2\lvert v_x\rvert} + \cdots$$
Taking the derivative with respect to $t$, we get
$$ \frac{d\lvert\mathrm{v}\rvert}{dt} = \frac{d\lvert v_x\rvert}{dt}+\left(-\frac{v_y^2}{2v_x^2}\frac{d\lvert v_x\rvert}{dt} + \frac{v_y}{\lvert v_x\rvert}\frac{d v_y}{dt} \right) + \cdots
$$
This is where we can see that the fact that using $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ to first order is all what matters: since $v_y=0$, everything from the second term onward is zero and we are left with $\frac{d\lvert\mathrm{v}\rvert}{dt} = \frac{d\lvert v_x\rvert}{dt}$.

**In short:** when in doubt, try to eliminate differentials and instead use derivatives directly. Most of the time statements like "$dv^2=0$" represent manipulation of a power series, in this case that second-order terms and above don't contribute to the first derivative.

Comment: I was going to write something similar but I think this is better.  Could you also add a paragraph addressing the OP’s comment on “same direction but a bit tilted”?  I think that would enrich this already good answer.  I.e. apply the same analysis to $\arctan(y/x)$ to see that the angle has a non-zero derivative.

Comment: @ErickWong I can't write any more right now, unfortunately.  I think you could write your own answer addressing this point, and it might even be closer to what Mercury was looking for.

Comment: What you calculate for me is the derivative at t=o when there is no dv which is added in the next moment 0+dt. Of course velocity would not change at t=0 and so the derivative is 0. v(y) is added at 0+dt and is not 0 but dv. Then the derivative in your formula is not 0. But second order of dv. I can not see how one can add dv in y direction and claim that v has the same magnitude? It is only possible when (dv)2 is 0 because dv is infinitesimal, which is not rigorous. Even so anyway then the direction of v would not change. In nature it changes, so (dv)2 is not 0.

Comment: @Mercury Solutions to differential equations "in nature" don't operate by Euler's method (that's where you would take $v+dv$ to update $v$ in the next time step, essentially).  In fact, this thing you're pointing out explains why using Euler's method for gravitational mechanics fails to be accurate -- it overshoots in this situation!

Comment: You have to remember that $dv$ in $\sqrt{v^2+(dv)^2}$ is not a real number. If you want, it's an infinitesimal in what's called nonstandard analysis, where it has a rigorous interpretation. The power series expansion of this is $v + (dv)^2/2v + (dv)^4/8v^3 + ...$, and so we see the expression has only second-order infinitesimals and higher.  An nth-order infinitesimal contributes only to the nth derivative, so the lack of first-order infinitesimals means the magnitude of $\mathrm{v}$ does not change through time.  (If you only care about first-order rate of change, you can set $(dv)^2=0$.)

Comment: It is true that v changes with second order of dv. But I can not understand why is second order of dv equal to 0 while dv is >0 (it is never 0). Thinking practically (physically) it is order smaller and can be thrown away. But mathematically rigorous for me it is not zero. Even it can be regarded as small as dv, because for every as much  small (dv)2 one can take a lower value of dv. E.g (dv)2 is as close to 0 as dv is. So is (dv)2 proven to be 0, or this just a (physics) approximation?

Comment: @Mercury There's no way to talk about mathematical rigorousness without saying precisely what you mean by $dv$.  In most ways of making $dv$ rigorous, "one can take a lower value of $dv$" is a meaningless statement since it is not a quantity, and there is no way to even ask whether or not $(dv)^2=0$.  The point is that $dv$ is a device to let you reason about functions and their first derivatives.  Second-order derivatives at a particular point in time do not affect functions or their first derivatives at that time.  Therefore, by acting as if $(dv)^2=0$, you can calculate what's relevant.

Comment: But as you see, you have to be careful with this sort of reasoning because it can lead to counter-intuitive results.  You need to know you can back them up with a "real" calculus calculation, like I've demonstrated in my answer.  Perhaps pick up a textbook on nonstandard analysis if you want to see how to rigorously deal with differentials as free-standing objects.  (I'm only passingly familiar, so I can't recommend any, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

$dv$ is not even a number in math, this is another kind of object, so physicists clearly abuse some natural ways of understanding and visualising the differential. In math, expressions like $v^2 + (dv)^2$ or $v + dv$ usually make no sense.

Comment: (+1) I prefer this answer because it hits the nail on the head. Apparently, I am the only one :(

Comment: @Peter thanks for your support :)

Comment: There are certainly contexts where your claims apply, but this seems to ignore the sort of calculations in many calculus textbooks where differentials are used to represent small real-valued quantities when using derivatives for approximations.

Comment: @TimurBakiev For me it is absolutely unclear what you want to say! Do you mean that infinitesimals are pseudoscience or what? What is their connection with reality of nature? For me as a physicist is interesting what means: "v+dv make no sense usually"?!

Comment: @Mercury it means that this is a mistake, it’s like to add a scalar to a vector. $dv$ is a linear functional. You should understand, that “infinitesimals” are not something you can visualize straightforwardly. Your question contains a paradox, because you are treating $dv$ as something small, but not infinitely small. That’s not a right approach. Actually, it had taken ages for science to deal with all such paradoxes. Finally, it was able to do that, when the analysis was formalized.

Comment: Ok in the end what do nature add to the vector v? Of course in math you can add functional whatever you like but nature adds velocity! What also changes if analysis is formalized?

Comment: @Mercury nature is nature, you may think it adds velocity, but then one day you will find that planets move along straight lines, and nothing is added at all. Nature is beyond our minds. But the only thing that is true for sure, nature is self-consistent, free from paradoxes. That’s what it has in common with math.

Comment: What you insists if far from observations. Who claims that planets move in straight lines? Surely if Earth is moving in straight line, soon there will be no sun light.

Comment: @Mercury that’s what the relativity theory claims, the meaning of a line is slightly more general, however

Comment: Relativity says that the space-time is curved by the great masses and that bodies travel on that curved space-time following its curvature. That is the same as travelling on a orbit but only the reason is different than the reason Newton proposed. But I never heard that Newton failed because he can not add dv to v.

Comment: @Mercury Newton succeeded because he realized there’s something wrong with $v + dv$. Then he and Leibniz established differential and integral calculus. Probably, they wanted to find an answer on the same question as you :)

Comment: For me exactly what they established does not work, because adding dv makes v greater -> v+dv>v which is not the case on a steady orbit.

Comment: @Mercury you still think wrong. You should understand, that if you add an infinite amout of “zeros”, the result can be either zero, or a finite number, or infinity. This is because such zeros are not usual numbers. So you can’t treat them as usual numbers. To get some usual number from $dv$, one has to integrate. In the answer above (which I upvoted) the author tries to explain, that it is possible to add such zeros in a very unexpected way: the direction changes, but the module remains unchanged, and why it happens.

Comment: He explains that the module doesn't change to first order of dv. (which is obvious). But not to second order of dv. And what does change the direction? The second order of dv? Is it that the module increases to second order of dv, while the vector itself to first order? I don't think so. So if the module doesn't change so doesn't the direction, because it also is up to second order.

Comment: @Mercury that’s exactly because the module increases to the second order, and the vector itself to the first order. The derivative of $v$ is always perpendicular to $v$. The vector rotates, and rotations preserve the module. What you’re calling $dv$, I think, is an approximation of the integral of the derivative. By the Lagrange mean value theorem, the smaller $dv$ gets, the closer it is to $v’ dt$.

Comment: @Mercury Why do you say the direction is the same up to the second order?  The direction changes in the first order term.